# How to run a shell command at analysis time in bazel?

Tags: versioning, bazel

I'm trying to bake the mercurial version into my Bazel file, so that I can get something like this:

```
# These I set manually, since they're "semantic"
MAJOR_VERSION = 2
MINOR_VERSION = 3
BUGFIX_VERSION = 1

# This should be the result of `hg id -n`
BUILD_VERSION = ?

apple_bundle_version(
    name = "my_version",
    build_version = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, BUGFIX_VERSION, BUILD_VERSION),
    short_version_string = "{}.{}.{}".format(MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, BUGFIX_VERSION),
)
```

This obviously is not hermetic, so I know it violates some of Bazel's assumptions, so I'm open to other options.

Here's some possible options:

1. Actually run `hg id -n` during Bazel analysis, which I don't know how to do.
2. Pass the build version in via command line, e.g., `--define=build_version=$(hg id -n)`. Unfortunately, this requires a separate command to wrap `bazel build`.
3. Manually set the `BUILD_VERSION`. Obviously, this would be annoying.

Is there a way to do #1? What are my other options?

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting the title to read "How to include automatically generated version info in a Bazel build?". It's more specific to your question, isn't it? After all, you do _not_ need a _generic_ way for executing a shell command at analysis time, do you? (It's a useful question, by the way, because Google's documentation leaves things to be desired. And people would find your question more easily with a different title, I assume.)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can do this with a custom `--workspace_status_command` and a genrule that processes the information and generates source files with this data.

EDIT: I removed the parts about the `--stamp` flag, it's not needed.

### Summary

1. Build with `--workspace_status_command=/path/to/binary` with a custom binary or shell script that runs `hg` and outputs the information you need.
2. Write a `genrule` with `stamp=1`.

### Details

#### 1. `--workspace_status_command=/path/to/binary`

The [`--workspace_status_command=<path>`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html) flag lets you specify a binary.

Bazel runs this binary before each build. The binary should write key-value pairs to stdout. Bazel partitions the keys into two buckets: "stable" and "volatile". (The names "stable" and "volatile" are a bit counter-intuitive, so don't think much about them.)

Bazel then writes the key-value pairs into two files:

- `bazel-out/stable-status.txt` contains all keys and values where the key's name starts with `STABLE_`
- `bazel-out/volatile-status.txt` contains the rest of the keys and their values

The contract is:

- "stable" keys' values should change rarely, if possible. If the contents of `stable-status.txt` change, it invalidates the actions that depend on them, e.g. the `genrule.cmd` if that genrule has `stamp=1`. In other words, if a stable key's value changes, it'll make Bazel rebuild stamped actions. Therefore the stable status should not contain things like timestamps, because they change all the time, and would make Bazel rebuild the stamped actions with each build.
- "volatile" keys' values may change often. Bazel expects them to change all the time, like timestamps do, and duly updates the `volatile-status.txt` file. In order to avoid rebuilding stamped actions all the time though, Bazel pretends that the volatile file *never changes*. In other words, if the volatile status file is the only one whose contents changed, that will not invalidate actions that depend on it. If other inputs of the actions have changed, then Bazel rebuilds that action, and the action may then use the updated volatile status. But just the volatile status changing alone will not invalidate the action.

Example for `my-status.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo STABLE_GIT_BRANCH $(git rev-parse HEAD)
echo MY_TIMESTAMP $(date)
```

#### 2. Write a `genrule` with `stamp=1`.

This attribute is undocumented, which surprises me. I'll file a bug about that.

Example for `foo/BUILD`:

```
genrule(
    name = "x",
    srcs = ["input.txt"],
    outs = ["x.txt"],
    cmd = " ; ".join([
        "( echo 'volatile data:'",
        "cat bazel-out/volatile-status.txt",
        "echo ---",
        "echo 'stable data:'",
        "cat bazel-out/stable-status.txt",
        ") > $@",
    ]),
    stamp = 1,
)
```

### Putting it all together

#### The genrule isn't rebuilt

...when only `bazel-out/volatile-status.txt` changes:

```
  $ bazel build --workspace_status_command=/tmp/foo/ws.sh //foo:x &>/dev/null && cat bazel-genfiles/foo/x.txt
volatile data:
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379211456
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:20:11 CET 2017
---
stable data:
BUILD_EMBED_LABEL 
BUILD_HOST <redacted>
BUILD_USER <redacted>
STABLE_GIT_BRANCH d3fed125d00f6f61bfbfe05f4566656cdac1ea6e

  $ cat bazel-out/volatile-status.txt 
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379425898
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:23:45 CET 2017

  $ bazel build --workspace_status_command=/tmp/foo/ws.sh //foo:x &>/dev/null && cat bazel-genfiles/foo/x.txt
volatile data:
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379211456
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:20:11 CET 2017
---
stable data:
BUILD_EMBED_LABEL 
BUILD_HOST <redacted>
BUILD_USER <redacted>
STABLE_GIT_BRANCH d3fed125d00f6f61bfbfe05f4566656cdac1ea6e

  $ cat bazel-out/volatile-status.txt 
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379441919
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:24:01 CET 2017
```

#### The genrule is rebuilt

...when the stable status or the genrule's inputs change:

```
  $ echo bar > foo/input.txt 

  $ bazel build --workspace_status_command=/tmp/foo/ws.sh //foo:x &>/dev/null && cat bazel-genfiles/foo/x.txt
volatile data:
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379566646
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:26:06 CET 2017
---
stable data:
BUILD_EMBED_LABEL 
BUILD_HOST <redacted>
BUILD_USER <redacted>
STABLE_GIT_BRANCH d3fed125d00f6f61bfbfe05f4566656cdac1ea6e


  $ git checkout HEAD~1 &>/dev/null

  $ bazel build --workspace_status_command=/tmp/foo/ws.sh //foo:x &>/dev/null && cat bazel-genfiles/foo/x.txt
volatile data:
BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1512379594890
MY_TIMESTAMP Mon Dec 4 10:26:34 CET 2017
---
stable data:
BUILD_EMBED_LABEL 
BUILD_HOST <redacted>
BUILD_USER <redacted>
STABLE_GIT_BRANCH b3da717469e23f5293297175a80709956416fd2c
```

Comment: I can see how this gives me the version info in, e.g., a C++ file; but how do I pass it to the `apple_bundle_version` macro listed in my question? I don't know how I'd get the result of the genrule passed to the macro.

Comment: That'd require running `hg` in the loading phase, and Bazel doesn't allow that. How does the macro use the `build_version` and `short_version_string` arguments? Can you rewrite the macro to read this information from a file (that the genrule I showed would generate)?

Comment: I don't own the macro (it's in the bazel project itself), defined here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_apple/blob/0119e91157fd3ad069bc75462796d28031c5b70f/apple/versioning.bzl#L66

Comment: I'll ping folks who maintain the Apple rules to answer.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `apple_bundle_version` rule uses regular expressions to parse whatever you pass in to `--embed_label` on the Bazel command line.

So, the simplest way to achieve this would be first writing something like this:

`bazel build //your:target --embed_label="$(hd id -n)"`

That will set `BUILD_EMBED_LABEL` to the your Mercurial version in your workspace info file, for example:

```
BUILD_EMBED_LABEL 156
BUILD_HOST ...
BUILD_USER ...
```

Then you have to tell `apple_bundle_version` what your version numbers should look like:

```
VERSION_PREFIX = "{}.{}.{}".format(MAJOR, MINOR, BUGFIX)

apple_bundle_version(
    name = "my_version",
    # This is where you define that BUILD_EMBED_LABEL will look like
    # this, where each thing inside {} is one of the capture groups
    # below. So in this case, it will be a number.
    build_label_pattern = "{build}",
    capture_groups = {
        "build": "\d+",
    },
    # CFBundleVersion should be the VERSION_PREFIX above, plus a dot
    # followed by {build} extracted from BUILD_EMBED_LABEL.
    build_version = VERSION_PREFIX + ".{build}",
    # CFBundleShortVersionString will just be the VERSION_PREFIX.
    short_version_string = VERSION_PREFIX,
)
```

Something like that should do the trick.

### Getting more advanced

If you don't want to manually pass the result of `hg id -n` each time you build, the `apple_bundle_version` rule is extensible so you can make it happen automatically. The only requirement of the `version` attribute on `ios_application` and related rules is that it point to a target that returns an [`AppleBundleVersionInfo`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_apple/blob/master/doc/providers.md#AppleBundleVersionInfo) provider—it doesn't have to be `apple_bundle_version`.

That provider propagates a small JSON file containing your bundle version and short bundle version string, so you could write your own rule that invokes `hg id -n` as a custom action, writes it out to a JSON formatted file with the right keys, and then use that target as your `version` attribute on your application instead.