# How to use genrule output as string to expand_template substitutions in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

It seems that the genrule can only output a Target, and the expand_template substitutions accept only string_dict, how can I use the genrule output to expand_template?

gen.bzl

```py
def _expand_impl(ctx):
    ctx.actions.expand_template(
        template = ctx.file._template,
        output = ctx.outputs.source_file,
        substitutions = {
            "{version}": ctx.attr.version,
        }
    )

expand = rule(
    implementation = _expand_impl,
    attrs = {
        "version": attr.string(mandatory = True),
        "_template": attr.label(
            default = Label("//version:local.go.in"),
            allow_single_file = True,
        ),
    },
    outputs = {"source_file": "local.go"},
)
```

BUILD

```py
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")

filegroup(
    name = "templates",
    srcs = ["local.go.in"],
)

genrule(
    name = "inject",
    outs = ["VERSION"],
    local = 1,
    cmd = "git rev-parse HEAD",
)

load(":gen.bzl", "expand")

expand(
    name = "expand",
    version = ":inject",
)

go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = [
        "default.go",
        ":expand", # Keep
    ],
    importpath = "go.megvii-inc.com/brain/data/version",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

and the local.go.in

```golang
package version

func init() {
    V = "{version}"
}
```

I expect the {version} in local.go.in can be replace by `git rev-parse HEAD` output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `substitutions` argument of `ctx.actions.expand_template()` must be known during the analysis phase (i.e., when `_expand_impl` is run), which happens before the `git rev-parse HEAD` command of the genrule would be run (i.e., during the execution phase).

There are a few ways to do this. The simplest is to do everything in the genrule:

```
genrule(
    name = "gen_local_go",
    srcs = ["local.go.in"],
    outs = ["local.go"],
    local = 1,
    cmd = 'sed "s/{VERSION}/$(git rev-parse HEAD)/" "$<" > "$@"',
)
```

That relies on `sed` being available on the host machine, but any other sort of program that can input one file, modify the text, and output it to another file will work.

Another option is to use a combination of [--workspace_status_command](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--workspace_status_command)
There are more details here:
[How to run a shell command at analysis time in bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622645/how-to-run-a-shell-command-at-analysis-time-in-bazel/47630130#47630130)
The advantage of this approach is that it avoids local genrules.